# plt.imshow() of a single color image showing as black

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to show a light-gray image using `plt.imshow()`, but the image turns out black.

I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
test_image = np.zeros((3871, 2484))
test_image.fill(200)
plt.imshow(test_image, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

But ended up getting:

[image: A black image]

- Matplotlib version: 3.7.1
- Numpy version: 1.24.3
- Python version: 3.11.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the `vmin,vmax` parameters when you plot a single color image with [`plt.imshow(...)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html). Set `vmin=0` and `vmax=500` to get a gray image. If `vmin,vmax` are not specified, then they will be set to the min and max values of the image data. This means that all of your input data is equal to `vmin`, which is the darkest possible value (black).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

test_image = np.zeros((3871, 2484))
test_image.fill(200)
plt.imshow(test_image, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=500)
plt.show()
```